# Angular: how to set ngModel of a shallow component?

Tags: angular, unit-testing

Let's say I have a component `InputComponent`, which implements `ControlValueAccessor`. Now, I have `AnotherComponent`, which uses the first component like so:

`<my-input [(ngModel)]="text"></my-input>`

I am trying to test `AnotherComponent` and I have `NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA` option set.
In my test, I need to put some value into `ngModel` to simulate a user input.

Here is what I've tried:

```
const input = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('my-input'));
input.nativeElement.value = 'some string';
input.nativeElement.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));
fixture.detectChanges();
await fixture.whenStable();

// then I assert that AnotherComponent `text` property is equal to the one I set to `ngModel`
```

But `text` property is empty, what I am doing wrong?

P.S. added `TestBed` as requested, though, the test is pretty common.

```
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ AnotherComponent ],
      schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AnotherComponent);
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });
```

Comment: can you share the entire test? At least the testbed config

Answer (score 0):

For the `ngModel` to work, you also need to import the `FormsModule` in your test and the other component you are trying to communicate with:

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  imports: [ FormsModule ],
  declarations: [ AnotherComponent, InputComponent ],
  schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA]
})
.compileComponents();
```

Comment: So when I added `FormsModule` I got an error: `No value accessor for form control with unspecified name attribute`, so I added name to the `my-input` and got another error `No value accessor for form control with name: 'myname'`. As I understand, it complains because `my-input` is shallow and there is no reference to `ControlValueAccessor`

Comment: well then i guess a shallow unit test is not an option for this scenario :)

Comment: @PierreDuc to be more specific, whenever ngModel directive is initialized, it uses NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR providers array to fetch current value accessor he is working on, but my `InputComponent` is provided to `NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR` inside component declaration, which is ommited due to `NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA`

Comment: @LuninRoman Ah, took me a while to figure out what you wanted to do. You are not just testing the `AnotherComponent`, you are testing the integration of `AnotherComponent` with `InputComponent`. To test what you want, you need to declare the `InputComponent` as well in your TestBed, there is no way around that

Comment: @PierreDuc I am sorry for being unclear! Though, there is no any reason to test it against original child components, it is a unit test after all... Thank you for your time!

Comment: @LuninRoman unit test becomes an integration test real quick. There is a thin line, especially when there are UI components involved. Unit tests usually just test functions, their input and output. You tried to test whether another component emits an event so your 'tested' components gets updated. Which is perfectly fine for a unit test in UI, but to make it work, you do need to declare them simultaneously. You could however truly unit test the `InputComponent` by using a generic wrapper component inside the unit test and do the same as you did with the `AnotherComponent`

Comment: @PierreDuc that's a good point, though, what I mean is that it shouldn't be like that, in my case, when I want just to test integration, I shouldn't care about `InputComponent` implementation details. Any changes to `InputComponent` itself may affect `AnotherComponent`. Anyways, this is another topic, thank you for interesting discussion!